Norm of an Element depends upon the field extension as well?
Let $K$ be a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then I am wondering about properties of $N( \alpha)$, where $N$ denotes the norm of $\alpha$ with respect to the extension of fields $ \mathbb{Q} \subset K$. I know that the norm of an element is the product of $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ where $\sigma_i$ varies over real/complex embeddings of $K$.
Is the following correct?
1- The norm of $2$ as when $K= \mathbb{Q}$ is $2$, but norm of $2$ when $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $2^2$. The norm of $2$ when $K$ is a field extension of degree $n$ is $2^n$. What surprises me here is that the norm of an element inside the base field $\mathbb{Q}$ is also dependent on the extension we are considering. Would not it have been nice to define norm to be the $$\Big(\prod_{\sigma} \sigma(\alpha)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$.
Because in such cases, the norm elements of the base field would be fixed. Is there any reason that the definition of norm is the way it has been defined. I am always getting confused that the norm of elements of base field varies as well depending on the field extension.

By the way, norm is usually not defined like that. For any finite field extension $L/K$, the norm $N_{L/K}(\alpha)$ is usually defined as the determinant of the $K$-linear map $L\to L, x\to \alpha x$. And that obviously has to depend on the dimension - if $\alpha\in K$ then this determinant is equal to $\alpha^{[L:K]}$.
The norm is indeed equal to the product of the $\sigma(\alpha)$ in the case where $L/K$ is a separable extension. This always happens in the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ (or if $K$ is any field of characteristic zero), but not in general.

But should not we expect the norm of element in base field to be independent of the extension we are considering?

@zero2infinity no, we should not expect the norm map on a field extension to be independent of the extension when applying it to elements of the base field. Why do you think that would be helpful?  I suspect you have not worked much with the norm map, so you have some mistaken ideas about how it "should" behave.
